# How do I stop gtk.Entry from losing focus on arrow keypress?

Tags: python, gtk, focus, widget

I'm writing a Python GTK app that uses a gtk.Entry widget to forward keypresses to multiple other widgets. Unfortunately, it seems like GTK has a default binding that switches widget focus on the up and down arrow keys out of the Entry widget.

I want to disconnect this key-based focus switching, but leave mouse based focus switching in place. I can't seem to find where in the API I'd do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return True from a handler for the key-press-event signal to prevent the default handling: http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#signal-gtkwidget--key-press-event

Comment: Thank you. This might be helpful for people with the same issue as mine. I want the directional buttons to change some values in textboxes. I want this to happen throught the whole program, even when the texbox is not selected. So I catch that event, **change the textbox manually** and then return **true**, **so it doesn't change the focus to other widgets**.